# how to toggle the right class for checkbox listener?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jframe, jdom

[image: Class B extends Class A]

I have a GUI with a start button and a checkbox that creates multiple instances of Class A (A blueprint of my web service) based on given text input. The checkbox if checked writes some additional elements to the XML file (which is the main output of the entire application). Now I want to add an additional checkbox which will provide the GUI to create instances of Class B which extends Class A but provides some additional fields and logic.

My question is that how can I implement this required functionality?

Given there is a `createMyXML()` method in class C which is doing the same for hardcoded arguments as Class A or Class B for its methods, should I extend it to take one of the class as a parameter and create instances for required elements in the XML?

P.S. It is probable that this question may be too subjective but I wonder what could be the approach or the 'right way' to do it.

Class A Anatomy

```
public class A {

    private String id;

    private Vector<String> inputs;

    private Vector<String> outputs;

    //***Getters and Setters for above.***

}
```

Class C Anatomy

```
public class C {
        void createMyXML(){
            for (A a : this.parser.getAttributes()){
                createFirstElement(A a);
                createSecondElement(A a);
            // Or (This behavior should be triggered by the checkbox)
                createFirstElement(B b);
                createSecondElement(B b);}
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider using the **Factory Design Pattern**?

Comment: @ahoxha should I be just converting A to an interface you say?

Comment: I added an answer. Please let me know if that meets your requirements?

Comment: @ahoxha Please review the updates. However, pardon me for deferred updations. I should have elaborated even more.

Comment: OK, I see. Are you overloading the `createFirstElement()` and `createSecondElement()` methods in `C`. If yes, you can modify the `I` interface, add these two methods and then implement them separately for `A` and `B`.

Comment: What do you mean by **Two `C` classes**???

Comment: @ahoxha No, right now I just have two different C (just to make sure their names are different but doing the same stuff just for different arguments) classes(C1 and C2) with the same method as A and B as arguments. Because, after your advice(which really seems to be the one) I have been trying to move around things in order to accommodate these changes. Also, as per my question, after I get the value of the checkbox ischecked() how I am supposed to toggle instances of A and B for these methods? I deleted the previous comment to avoid confusion for potential readers.

Comment: I think you can add the logic of `createFirstElement()` and `createSecondElement()` inside the `createMyXML()` method in `A` and `B` separately, and then just call the `createMyXML()` method inside `C`, and have `this.parser.getAttributes()` return `I`. This way, in `C` you don't care whether it's `A` or `B`, you wrap it with `I` and call the `createMyXML()` method.

Comment: @ahoxha C is where I have to care about the checkboxes to produce XMLs based upon different class instances which provide different types of data(some more, some less). The overall structure of Class C will remain same since it kind of represents a standard. A, B merely represent a blueprint of a service which may have different attributes and provide a variety of data.

Comment: OK, can you do this: in `C` create the instance of `A` or `B` depending on the **checkbox**'s value and then call the `createMyXML()` method? The `createMyXML()` method should know how to `createFirstElement()` and `createSecondElement()` (which would be done in `A` and `B`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142125/discussion-between-pythonlearn-and-ahoxha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want a way of creating different instances that would create XML files based on some logic that differs from class to class, preferably easily extendable later on.

In this case the [**Factory Design Pattern**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) seems like a reasonable solution. You define an interface with the `craeteMyXML()` method:

```
public interface I {
    public void createMyXML();
}
```

Add a class for each XML creation logic. In this example I've added two classes: `A` and `B`, which implement the `I` interface.

Class `A`:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class A implements I {

    private String id;
    private Vector<String> inputs;
    private Vector<String> outputs;

    @Override
    public void createMyXML() {
        System.out.println("Create XML by the rules of A.");
    }

    /* Getters and setters and other methods needed*/
}
```

Class `B`:

```
public class B implements I {

    @Override
    public void createMyXML() {
        System.out.println("Create XML by the rules of B.");
    }
}
```

You can use an `enum` as a parameter for the factory based on which it creates instances. You can use other options as well, for example a `String` value or `int`, it depends on your solution. Here, I define the available instances as an `enum`:

```
public enum Instance {
    A, B
}
```

The `Factory` class creates instance of `A` or `B` using the super-type `I`.

```
public class Factory {
    public static I createInstance(Instance i) {
        if (i == Instance.A) {
            return new A();
        } else if (i == Instance.B) {
            return new B();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding a `Test` class to quickly test this solution, you can incorporate it in your project.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I a = Factory.createInstance(Instance.A);
        I b = Factory.createInstance(Instance.B);
        
        a.createMyXML();
        b.createMyXML();
    }
}
```

When you execute this, it will produce the output:

> Create XML by the rules of A.
>
> Create XML by the rules of B.

Comment: It is actually a class C that has the `createMyXML()` method along with a bunch of other methods like `firstElement(A a)`.  And I need to toggle between A and B for these parameters.

Comment: Does the `createMyXML()` method behave the same way for all classes: `A`, `B` etc.?

Comment: Yes, it does but partially. Since the data for the XML elements come from these classes as they define inputs and outputs fields. However, as Class B provides additional data it is reflected as added elements in `createMyXML()`.